# Tensorflow Serving model is returning same output for different inputs

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I recently exported a text summarization model for tensorflow serving. I am able to run a client and make a gRPC call to the model successfully however regardless of what I send in as an input, I get the same output every time.  I am assuming that it has to do with the way I exported the model and perhaps it is using a static entry rather than the input I send in, however I'm not sure as to what I performed incorrectly.  I have verified that the passed data in the client file is correct, however regardless of what gets sent to self.stub.Predict, it is always the same output.  Anyone seen this before or possibly seen what I am doing wrong?

Client file snippet:

```
def decode(self, passed_data):
    now = datetime.now()

    self.request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
        #tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(test_data_set[0], shape=[1]))
        tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(passed_data, shape=[1]))
    result = self.stub.Predict(self.request, 5.0)
    waiting = datetime.now() - now
    return result, waiting.microseconds
```

Export Snippet:
    ....

```
decode_mdl_hps = hps._replace(dec_timesteps=1)
            model = seq2seq_attention_model.Seq2SeqAttentionModel(
                decode_mdl_hps, vocab, num_gpus=FLAGS.num_gpus)
            decoder = seq2seq_attention_decode.BSDecoder(model, batcher, hps, vocab)

            serialized_output = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_output')


            serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
            feature_configs = {
                'inputs': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[1], dtype=tf.string),
            }
            tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)

            saver = tf.train.Saver()#sharded=True)

            config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement = True)

            with tf.Session(config = config) as sess:

                # Restore variables from training checkpoints.
                ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
                if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
                    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
                    global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
                    print('Successfully loaded model from %s at step=%s.' %
                        (ckpt.model_checkpoint_path, global_step))
                    res = decoder._Decode(saver, sess)
                    res_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(res)

                    print("Decoder value {}".format(type(res)))
                else:
                    print('No checkpoint file found at %s' % FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
                    return

                # Export model
                export_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.export_dir,str(FLAGS.export_version))
                print('Exporting trained model to %s' % export_path)


                #-------------------------------------------

                tensor_info_inputs = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(serialized_tf_example)
                tensor_info_outputs = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(res_tensor)

                prediction_signature = (
                    tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
                        inputs={ tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_INPUTS: tensor_info_inputs},
                        outputs={tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_OUTPUTS:tensor_info_outputs},
                        method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
                        ))

                #----------------------------------

                legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
                builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

                builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
                    sess=sess, 
                    tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                    signature_def_map={
                        'predict':prediction_signature,
                    },
                    legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
                builder.save()

                print('Successfully exported model to %s' % export_path)
```

Comment: It looks like the tf.example gets fed in and parsed, but never gets fed to any model? Are you using `tf_example` anywhere?

Comment: Nope Allen...you hit it on the head. Sorry for the late response. Work was crazy this week and I'm just getting back to this. So in the call to _Decode was referencing the default paths with the batch data and not the value I was passing in.  Thanks for the help. This was stupidity on my part.  If you add the above as an answer, I will accept it as one.